# Theory of Automata concepts

Tags: computer-science, automata

I just started taking Theory of Automata and I'm having a hard time understanding some of the concepts. It's been only a week and the following questions are my homework. I'm not asking you to do my homework for me but I was just hoping someone could solve with explanations the first part (a) of each question so I can do the rest myself. So far I can only understand how automata's work on state diagrams. Everything other than that seems confusing. Hope someone can explain.

Thanks again.

[image]

Comment: Break the problem down. Can you create an automaton for this? $\{w | w $ has a least 3 $a$'s$\}$